# associations without the user_id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a FriendRequest.rb model in my Rails app with the following table columns.

```
 create_table "friend_requests", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "requesting_user_id"
    t.integer  "requested_friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

With relationships defined as you see below, I added this code to a `/views/users/show.html.erb` page show the friend requests that have been made for each user. However, I'm getting this error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column friend_requests.user_id does not exist
```

because, I obviously didn't create a user_id column. Is there a way that I can make this code work by adding more information to the relationships? or should I scrap my work and do it differently?

```
 <% for user in @user.friend_requests %>
  <li><%= h user.name %></li>
  <%= link_to "Add Friend", friend_requests_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %>
  <% end %>
```

User.rb

```
 has_many :friend_requests
```

FriendRequest.rb

```
   belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `has_many` association for:

```
has_many :friend_requests, foreign_key: 'requesting_user_id'
```

By default, Rails will look for [model_name]_id in the other table, this is why it is looking for `user_id`, but by adding the `foerign_key:` option, you can override this default behaviour and tell Rails what is the name of the foreign_key you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this configuration:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friend_requests
  has_many :requesters, through: friend_requests
end

class FriendRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :requester, foreign_key: 'requesting_user_id'
  belongs_to :requested, foreign_key: 'requested_friend_id'
  validates :requester_id, presence: true
  validates :requested_id, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Look especially for the options `:primary_key` and `:foreign_key`